# Return Value from async rest template spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, asynchronous, rest-client

I am creating a async rest call using spring

```
@GetMapping(path = "/testingAsync")
public String value() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    String baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/XXX";
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String value = "";

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", requestHeaders);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<User>> futureEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, User.class);

    futureEntity.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<User> result) {
            System.out.println(result.getBody().getName());
            // instead of this how can i return the value to the user ?
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {

        }
    });

    return "DONE"; // instead of done i want to return value to the user comming from the rest call 
}
```

And is there any way i can convert ListenableFuture to use CompletableFuture that is used in java 8 ?

Comment: Just return the `futureEntity` instead of `DONE`, Spring MVC will do the rest. Or create a `DefferedResult` and set the value of that result in the `onSuccess` and return the `Deferredresult` from your method.

Comment: with deffered result its working but not with futureentity, is there any way we can use completable future instead of listenablefuture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically 2 things you can do.

1. Remove the `ListenableFutureCallback` and simply return the `ListenableFuture`
2. Create a `DeferredResult` and set the value of that in a `ListenableFutureCallback`.

### Returning a `ListenableFuture`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/testingAsync")
public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<User>> value() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    String baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/XXX";
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String value = "";

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", requestHeaders);
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, User.class);
}
```

Spring MVC will add a `ListenableFutureCallback` itself to fill a `DeferredResult` and you will get a `User` eventually.

### Using a `DeferredResult`

If you want more control on what to return you can use a `DeferredResult` and set the value yourself.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/testingAsync")
public DeferredResult<String> value() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    String baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/XXX";
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String value = "";

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", requestHeaders);
    final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<User>> futureEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, User.class);

    futureEntity.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<User> result) {
            System.out.println(result.getBody().getName());
            result.setResult(result.getBody().getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            result.setErrorResult(ex.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: when i am using the first method its getting stuck and not returning the value in postman the second one works ? can you please help on that . One more trouble will this be good in terms of performance?

Comment: Generally you won't gain performance but you can do more with less resources. If you would need to do multiple calls to heavy resources, you could gain performance when those could be done in parallel.

Comment: And why is the first way not working without using deffered?How can we call multiple rest ends in the same can you just give a tiny bit of hint.

Comment: Not in comments or this question as that is a different questions. Not sure why the first isn't working, should work afaik (assuming you are on Spring 4.3 that is).

Comment: I am using spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about async calls in Spring but I would imagine that you could return the text that you want through the **ResponseBody**

It would look like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/testingAsync")
@ResponseBody
public String value() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
...
...
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<User> result) {
         return result.getBody().getName();
     }
...
}
```

Sorry if this isn't what you are asking about.

Comment: That won't work, due to the async nature of the call.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. Not sure how to solve this but I am eager to understand how to work with asynchronous tasks. If I were to think of hacky ways to go about this, I'd guess that you could delegate the responsibility of returning a value to a different function? i.e., maybe direct the onSuccess to another mapping called "/returnAsync" which then can return the value that you want?